# dynamic dependent select dropdown

Tags: php, functions, ajax, jquery, javascript

I have a dynamic dependent select dropdown system that selects vehicle makes and models from a database which works fine but I would like to convert it to use and select parent and child categories from wordpress rather than using the information from the sql dump. I have the post meta make and the post meta model and the model meta are child categories of the make meta. I'm just wondering how do I write my function to select the child categories of the selected parent categories and display them by AJAX. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is the php function I have so far:**

```
function make_model() {
$vehicle_make = $_REQUEST['id'];
global $wpdb;
$models = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM car_models WHERE model_id='".$vehicle_make."'",13,'gargle'),ARRAY_A);
foreach($models as $model) { 
echo '<option value="'.$model["model_id"].'">'.$model["model"].'</option>';
}
//echo $models;
die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_make_model' , 'make_model');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_make_model','make_model');
```

**Here is the html that outputs the select dropdown:**

```
<div id="contents">

<form name="form" method="post" action="">

    <label>Make: </label>

    <select name="vehicle_make" class="vehicle_make">

    <option>Select Make</option>

    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $vehicles = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM car_makes",13,'gargle'),ARRAY_A);
    foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) { 
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $vehicle["make_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $vehicle["make"]; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>

    </select>

    <label>Model: </label>

    <select name="vehicle_model" class="vehicle_model">

    <option>Select Model</option>

    </select>

</form>
```

**and finally the ajax jquery:**

```
$('.vehicle_make').change(function(){   
    var vehicle_make = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action : 'make_model',
            id : vehicle_make,
        },
        success: function(vehicle_model_data) {
            console.log(vehicle_model_data);
            $('.vehicle_model').html(vehicle_model_data);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Which parts of the code that you need help with?

Comment: @SallyCJ I need help with the php that connects to the database, instead of it connecting to the tables that I created and uploaded an sql dump into, I want to connect it to the wordpress post meta table where `car_makes` would be the parent category and `car_models` would be the child category of that parent category. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the drop-down being displayed on single posts pages? Or are you able to send the post ID via the form? Because it's needed for querying the *post* meta table. Also, the `car_makes` and `car_models`, their values are category IDs, right? Is the value a comma-separated list or an array (i.e. serialized string)?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes it's being displayed on a single post and a post archive page. Basically the way it works is the `car_makes` database has 2 tables, `make` which is the name of the make of the car and `make_id` which is an id number of the car make. `car_models` contains 3 tables `models` which is the name of the model of car, `model_id` and `make_id` which is meant to match the `make_id` from the `car_make` database. The ajax fetches the `make_id` from the data attribute of the dropdown of the car make and matches it to the `model` in the `car_models` database.

Comment: Ok, but I was actually referring to "*connect it to the wordpress post meta table where `car_makes` would be the parent category and `car_models` would be the child category of that parent category*" - are these *post meta* already exist and filled with the proper value(s)? If so, what are the values? Category IDs?

Comment: @SallyCJ Oh right sorry, my bad. Yes they already exist and yes they have values and yes the values are category id's.

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry they're custom taxonomies not categories, my bad...and they have tag ID's.

Comment: What are the custom taxonomies? E.g. `post_tag` for standard Tags, and `category` for standard Categories. And can you give an example of the possible values of the meta `car_makes` and `car_models`?

Comment: The custom taxonomies are called `listings` and the value for `car_makes` would be **Honda** for example and the `car_model` would be **Civic** for example...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Do you manually enter the meta *value* (e.g. the text "Honda"), or are you using plugin like Advanced Custom Fields?

Comment: @SallyCJ No worries. Yes I manually create the meta values.

Comment: Not sure if you still need help with this? ( well in case you already found a solution elsewhere :) ) If you do still need help, I have one last question.. do you only need help with the `make_model()` function, or also the part that builds the car *makes* drop-down menu options?

Comment: @SallyCJ Iam still looking for help with this and I need help with the make and model dropdowns.. thank you

Comment: @SallyCJ Just wondering if you have a minute to chat? Please reply when you do thanks....